# Can delegated authentication be used with external identity license?

Tags: identity, delegated-authentication, external

I am preparing for identity and access management exam and I can't find explaination why using External Identity licenses is not a valid option for marketing users which use third-party application for lead nurturing. Why identity licenses and platform licenses are both valid options for them? If Salesforce uses SSO and delegated authentication, is there any restriction of using delegated authentication with external identity license?

My understanding is that marketing users don't need platform licenses if they don't need to access Salesforce User Interface or Salesforce Platform. It seems to me that External Identity License might be a good choice for this case as well as usual identity licenses.